# how to remove duplicate line from text file vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to remove duplicated line from text file that contain for
example :

```
.abc
.def
.ghi
.abc
.abc
```

to get the result

```
.abc
.def
.ghi
```

Comment: plz post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.Add()` method of `HashSet(Of T)` which adding to set only new items. [HashSet(Of T) Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)

```vb
Dim path As String = "yourPath"
Dim lines As New HashSet(Of String)()
'Read to file
Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)
    Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
        lines.Add(sr.ReadLine())
    Loop
End Using

'Write to file
Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path)
    For Each line As String in lines
        sw.WriteLine(line)
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: u just have a small mistakes like `End For` ,, And Forgot to `Import System` and `Import System.IO`