# VB.NET Find Duplicate Lines in a Text File

Tags: vb.net, duplicates

I work for a company that deals with various import files of all different sizes.  I would like to develop a pre-check on these files to find and identify any duplicate lines (where the entire line matches another line in the file).  I have written code for this already, but as the line count of the file gets above 100,000, the code starts to really slow down.  How can I make this code run faster and keep the code simple?

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader(txtFile.Text)
While Not sr.EndOfStream
    i += 1
    ' Save the header of the file if requested
    If chkKeepHeader.Checked And i = 1 Then
        sHLine = sr.ReadLine
    End If
    sLine = sr.ReadLine

    ' Compare the current line with the previous lines read
    If lstDistLines.Contains(sLine) Then
        iDupCount += 1
        lstDupLines.Add(i & "," & sLine)
    Else
        lstDistLines.Add(sLine)
    End If

    ' Update the display at regular intervals
    If i Mod (50) < 1 Then
        lblProcessCount.Text = i
        Application.DoEvents()
    End If
End While
sr.Close()
sr.Dispose()
sr = Nothing
```

Comment: If dups are found what do you want to do with them. Keep a count, do something else etc? Also if you are asking for review, that's best over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com . There are many things you could do but as mentioned it's best at the review site :)

Comment: All duplicate lines need to be reported to the user along with the original line number so that they can be found easily in the original file.  I do this by storing the duplicate lines in a separate file.

Comment: Import the lines into a database table (two columns, one for the line number, and the third a VARCHAR/NVARCHAR to hold the line content), and use the DB to find duplicates using SQL. You can then show the user the line number that are duplicated. (You asked for speed, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on keeping track of the process ( updating the `lblProcessCount` and `Application.DoEvents()` take a lot of the time ), you can use `HashSet` instead of `lstDistLines` to store the lines. HashSet does not allow duplicates, but checking if it contains an item takes almost the same time no matter how many items you add to it.

[how to remove duplicate line from text file vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307266/how-to-remove-duplicate-line-from-text-file-vb-net)

Comment: I like this, but the issue is that the duplicate lines are seen as invalid data.  Those who import the files will want to report the duplicate lines back to those who produced the import files.

Comment: @Acavier you still need to keep the `lstDupLines` list, just change the type of `lstDistLines` from `List` to `HashSet` and you can keep the rest of the code as it is. The link is just for sample use of `HashSet`

Comment: That simple change did it!  Thank you.  A file of almost 600,000 lines went very fast.